# NullInjectorError: No provider for SwUpdate! when running ng test

Tags: angular

I made an `Angular 8.2.14` PWA with a service worker that runs fine in `dev` and `prod` mode.

But when I run the tests with the `ng test` command, I get the following error:

```
NullInjectorError: No provider for SwUpdate!
```

The service worker is imported as:

```
imports: [
  ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
],
```

and is used as:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private swUpdate: SwUpdate,
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.swUpdate.isEnabled) {
      this.swUpdate.available.subscribe(() => {
        const appNewVersion = this.translateService.instant('app.new_version_available');
        if (confirm(appNewVersion)) {
          window.location.reload();
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

My test is:

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        MatGridListModule
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The console log output:

```
Chromium 80.0.3987 (Linux 0.0.0) AppComponent should render title FAILED
        NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[AppComponent -> SwUpdate]: 
          StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppComponent -> SwUpdate]: 
            NullInjectorError: No provider for SwUpdate!
        error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'AppComponent', Function ], ngDebugContext: DebugContext_({ view: Object({ def: Object({ factory: Function, nodeFlags: 33669121, rootNodeFlags: 33554433, nodeMatchedQueries: 0, flags: 0, nodes: [ Object({ nodeIndex: 0, parent: null, renderParent: null, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 0, flags: 33554433, childFlags: 114688, directChildFlags: 114688, childMatchedQueries: 0, matchedQueries: Object({  }), matchedQueryIds: 0, references: Object({  }), ngContentIndex: null, childCount: 1, bindings: [  ], bindingFlags: 0, outputs: [  ], element: Object({ ns: '', name: 'app-root', attrs: [  ], template: null, componentProvider: Object({ nodeIndex: 1, parent: <circular reference: Object>, renderParent: <circular reference: Object>, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 1, flags: 114688, childFlags: 0, directChildFlags: 0, childMatchedQueries: 0, matchedQueries: Object, matchedQueryIds: 0, references: Object, ngContentIndex: -1,  ...
            at <Jasmine>
            at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:855:1)
            at resolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17514:1)
            at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17440:1)
            at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17266:1)
            at resolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17514:1)
            at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17440:1)
            at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17266:1)
            at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:30393:1)
            at NgModuleRef_.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:31578:1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the issue is in your test:

```js
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        MatGridListModule
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

In a test, you're building a module with all dependencies that your component requires.

Your component depends on `SwUpdate`, your test module does not have it neither in `imports`, nor in `providers`.

You either need to inject a real or (preferably) a fake instance of `SwUpdate` to your TestBed module for it at least to compile.

You could mock `SwUpdate` class by creating it in a separate file, I've taken this code from https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit/blob/master/application/src/app/services/swUpdate-server.mock.service.ts

```js
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { UpdateActivatedEvent, UpdateAvailableEvent } from '@angular/service-worker/src/low_level';

export class SwUpdateServerMock {
  public available: Observable<UpdateAvailableEvent> = new Subject();
  public activated: Observable<UpdateActivatedEvent> = new Subject();
  public isEnabled: boolean = false;

  public checkForUpdate(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve());
  }
  public activateUpdate(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve());
  }
}
```

And then in testing module, tell TestBed module to use `SwUpdateServerMock` instead of `SwUpdate`.

```js
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        MatGridListModule
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: SwUpdate, useClass: SwUpdateServerMock }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

So basically this will inject a fake service.

You might try injecting real `SwUpdate` class and then use Jasmine helpers to stub them:

```js
spyOn(swUpdate, 'isEnabled').and.returnValue(false);
```

As an example. This should work but might require some further adjustments

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But is a copy of my test source code your solution ?

Comment: It is not. Let me do a quick update with a possible solution.

Comment: @Stephane the code above is minimum to to compile. In order to test this properly, I'd advice looking at jasmine stubs, being able to spy on methods. Understanding those will enable you to write better tests.

Comment: I progressed to the next missing service. So I suppose I should mock all my services, quite a few of them ! But first I'll refresh on my Angular testing knowledge.

Comment: You don't have to mock all of your services, to be honest. It's been a while, but I do recall that I have injected real services and then just stubbed them with Jasmine helpers. Added sample above